Conditional layouts based on page number & total of pages in ConTeXt
I've been writing a small module where only the first page shows the header and only the last one shows the footer (and if the document has only one page it shows both), so for example when it has three (or more) pages it will kind of look like this (note that the first page only shows the header, the second page has no header nor footer, but last page has only the footer):

A document with only two pages will look like this (first page only with the header, last page only with the footer):

And a document that only has one page will show both header and footer:

Knowing that you can set a different layout for specific page numbers, the first page, the last page or odd or even pages (as described in the "Multiple layouts" section at the Page Layout wiki page) I made it kind of work, but this needs to be adjusted every time the number of pages change. For example this will work just fine when the document renders two pages:
\setuppapersize[A8]
\showframe
\setupbodyfont[10pt]
\setupinterlinespace[line=4mm]

\setuplayout[
    top=\baselineskip,
    topdistance=\baselineskip,
    bottom=\baselineskip,
    bottomdistance=\baselineskip,
    header=\baselineskip,
    headerdistance=\baselineskip,
    footer=\baselineskip,
    footerdistance=\baselineskip,
    topspace=\dimexpr(\topheight + \topdistance),
    height=fit,
    width=fit,
]

\definelayout[first][footer=\zeropoint]
\definelayout[last][header=\zeropoint]

\setupheadertexts[I'm a header!]
\setupfootertexts[I'm a footer!]

\starttext
    \input hawking
\stoptext

But when the number of pages goes beyond 2, I found myself needing to throw a
\definelayout[<pagenumber>][header=\zeropoint,footer=\zeropoint]

for each page the document rendered. Also, if I use this very same example with text that renders only one page, the document will have only the footer.
So my question is, is there any conditional approach that lets you to change the page layout based on the total number of pages so what I was trying to describe above can be achieved?

There are probably nicer ways, but you can play with this:
\setuppapersize[A6]
\showframe
\setupbodyfont[10pt]
\setupinterlinespace[line=4mm]

\setupheadertexts[I'm a header!]
\setupfootertexts[I'm a footer!]

\setuplayout[
    top=\baselineskip,
    topdistance=\baselineskip,
    bottom=\baselineskip,
    bottomdistance=\baselineskip,
    header=\zeropoint,
    headerdistance=\baselineskip,
    footer=\zeropoint,
    footerdistance=\baselineskip,
    topspace=\dimexpr\topheight + \topdistance\relax,
    height=fit,
    width=fit,
]

\ifnum\lastpage>1\relax
  \definelayout[first][header=\baselineskip]
  \definelayout[last][footer=\baselineskip]
\else
  \setuplayout[header=\baselineskip,footer=\baselineskip]
\fi

\starttext
  We have \lastpage\ pages.
%   \dorecurse{1}{\samplefile {hawking}\par}
%   \dorecurse{5}{\samplefile {hawking}\par}
  \dorecurse{10}{\samplefile {hawking}\par}
\stoptext

You can uncomment at the bottom to have one, two, or three pages. It seems to work in this case.
The request is a bit odd to me. Why not just put the "I'm a header" content at the top of your document and "I'm a footer" content last (with some fill first to make it go to the bottom)? That seems to give the same result.

Yes this seems to work, thank you. I know you could do what you just said but I need to adapt a bunch of documents to a new format where for some reason they set the headers and footers to work that way so figured out it was easier to try to set those documents to a new template rather than edit them one by one so they fit the new format.
